# how does Spring's task scheduler work?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to implement the ability to schedule tasks for a later time. I'm hoping the behavior is that when I schedule a task it puts it in a queue if there are no free threads. This doesn't seem to be the case for me.

I have a java bean that implements Runnable and I schedule the task to run at 5 pm, but if I schedule another task to run at 5 pm, it does not run, only the first task does. Is there a way to have these tasks queue up and run one after another at 5pm?

Thanks

This is how my threadPoolTaskScheduler is set up:

```
<bean id="threadPoolTaskScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="poolSize" value="5" />
</bean>
```

And my code. My service layer calls runTask() which in turn is called by my ui layer.

```
public class MySchedulerForTask {

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler

    public void runTask() {
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(new MyTask(), atFive())
    }

    private Date atFive() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        cal.set(MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(SECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    public class MyTask implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            //Calls my DAO to update stuff.
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Why not make an overarching task that executes both at 5pm?

Comment: I should probably say that several tasks could potentially be scheduled at 5pm. I guess I could create a separate thread that holds a queue of runnables and runs each one at 5 pm, but I'm hoping it'll be easier than that.

Comment: Show us your code and relevant config, please.

Comment: How tasks are executed depends on the configured `TaskExecutor` scheduling and executing are 2 different things, the first is done with the `TaskScheduler`, the second with the `TaskExecutor`. To determine what happens in your case we need to see some code/configuration.

Comment: I believe a `TaskExecutor` has a queue, but does a `TaskScheduler`?